# What is the difference between two conversions from Long to ByteArray?

Tags: kotlin

```
import java.lang.Long as JLong
import java.lang.Byte as JByte
import java.nio.ByteBuffer

fun Long.toByteArray1() = 
    ByteBuffer.allocate(JLong.SIZE / JByte.SIZE)
        .putLong(this)
        .array()

fun Long.toByteArray2() =
    this.toString()
        .toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a1: ByteArray = 10L.toByteArray1()
    val a2: ByteArray = 10L.toByteArray2()
    println("a1 = ${a1.toString()}")
    println("a1 = ${ByteBuffer.wrap(a1).getLong()}")
    println("a2 = ${a2.toString()}")
    println("a2 = ${String(a2, Charsets.UTF_8)}")
}
```

What is the difference between toByteArray1() and toByteArray2()?

If I send the bytes into the outputstream what receiver will get?

Comment: FYI `"a1 = ${a1.toString()}"` is the same as `"a1 = $a1"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are completely different.

- `.toByteArray1()` returns bytes of the signed long number (therefore it should contain exactly 8 bytes = 64 bits):

  ```
  println(0.toByteArray1().size) // 8
  println(1234.toByteArray1().size) // 8
  ```
- `.toByteArray2()` first converts the long to `String` and then to the byte array with the `String` characters encoded in UTF-8 (since there are only digits, they are encoded one byte each), and the byte array in this case contains the same number of bytes as the length of the string representation:

  ```
  println(0.toByteArray2().size) // 1
  println(-1234.toByteArray2().size) // 5
  println(123456789012.toByteArray2().size) // 12
  ```

And, of course, the decoders should be different, as in your example where you decode `a1` and `a2`.

Comment: Thanks! For example, if the protocol use string commands just converted into byte array the I should use toByteArray2()? If the protocol is special binary format then toByteArray1() maybe usefull?

Comment: @AndreiSibircevs If your protocol uses string commands, just convert the number to string.